# Push/Pop UIViewController Animation effect same as a camera filters and full camera view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uianimation, catransition

I have have create 2 separate view controller for create functionality same as iPhone camera screen with all defaults filters.

Functionality working as per my requirements.

Now I have issue with view animation. How can I achieve same effect while user press on filter icon (left corner) in default camera and full camera screen after selecting any filter.

Look at below screen for more.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIView for your filter options instead of UIViewController. Then you can animate whatever you want on the view.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108

Comment: if I maintain all in single uiviewcontroller then memory leak issue has been occurs.